# Tax Deductible Expenses for a dual use property (US)

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

I've got a home that I live in and rent out rooms. I'm wondering which expenses I can deduct from taxes and what percent of them I can deduct.

Specifically, can I deduct

- Repainting the house
- Repairs
- Improvements (like new furniture)

I heard from someone that for common areas, I can only deduct the percentage matching the percent of the house that is rented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IRS Publication 527](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p527) addresses these questions, particularly the section on [Renting Part of Property](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p527#en_US_2017_publink1000219159).

Please read for yourself but the gist, I believe, is:

- Paint your tenant's room, you can deduct the paint because the room is rented.
- Paint your room, you can't because it's personal use.
- Paint the house, deduct part determined "by any reasonable method" such as square footage of rented part, or number of rooms rented out, since it's common.